# How do I export a union of literals type without using an intermediate name?

Tags: typescript

My file is very simple, however I feel it should be simpler still...

```
type wevs = "xxxs"|"xxs"|"xs"|"sm"|"md"|"lg"|"xl"|"xxl"|"xxxl"
export default wevs
```

How do I write this without the "wevs" ?

Comment: it is impossible. believe me, your file is simple enough

Comment: Lol, thank you @captain-yossarian . I guess that's why all that googling didn't turn up an answer! Maybe this post will spare some other poor soul 15 minutes some time! If you want to write that as an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do in TypeScript. The rules are simple. In order to use some type you should declare it using either `type` or `interface`. You can also use `enum`, `namespace` and `class` keywords for declaring a type but these are not erased from the bundle.

There are no alternative ways of using type signature without declaring the name.